# What is the idiom or single word for a person who just talks high-flying to show himself important and powerful?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What is the idiom or single word for a person who just talks high-flying to show himself important and powerful? But, in actuality, he is not what he tries to portray himself as.

Comment: a *braggart*, a *poser*...

Comment: Donald Trumpeteer?

Comment: Among an older male generation in Britain he would be called a *bull shitter*.